# Searching the binary table

Tags: java, search, binary-data

I have a question: Can some one give me an example of searching the binary table to find the change from 1 to 0? For example, one line have

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

and it should give me 2 changes. I want to search only one line.

Comment: Well, assuming the line above is a string, you loop left to right, starting at `i=1` and going while `i < line.length` while doing the check `if (line[i - 1] == 1 && line[i] == 0) changes++;` on each loop iteration.

Comment: Make an attempt and post it here if you cannot figure it out.  This way you can learn better.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it was really helpfull, nem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for(int i=1; i< binarytableline.length; i++){ 
if (binarytableline[i - 1] == 1 && line[i] == 0) changes++;      
 }
```

Remember that the indexes start at zero:

[image]
(Java docs)

Essentially, whats happening in the code above is that we are looping through the line. Now, i is the index. Lets start at the beginning of the loop.

```
i=1
```

So, binarytableline[1-1] = the first index of the binary table line, or the very first number. Now, we are seeing if it equals `1`, and the second index, which is `i`, equals `0`. To check, we do the following:

```
binarytableline[i - 1] == 1 && line[i] == 0
```

This would mean that there **is** a change in binary digits from one digit to the next, and in our example that is the 0th index to the first. Now, we would iterate our variable, `changes` by 1 by doing `changes++`. Again, this is in a for loop, meaning we will loop through all the elements like this. The amount of times it has changed will be recorded in `int changes`.

Let me know if this helped,

Ruchir

Comment: Thank you very much, it was big help, you made me understand this :)

Comment: @Natalia No problem Natalia! I'm glad to help. Your binary table was an int array, right?

Comment: Yea, it was Integer type @Ruchir Baronia :)